# Httparty - appending to url and adding headers to get request via Ruby class

Tags: ruby, http, append, httparty

I'm currently working with `Httparty` to make a `GET` Seamless.giv API which returns field from a form. In the requests there are Authentication headers that need to be passed in order to access the API. But the request has to be made to a specific form. Thats where the issue lays should this be in the base URI or appended?

Here is the `curl` example of the request:

```
curl -X GET -H "AuthDate: 1531236159"\
 -H "Authorization: HMAC-SHA256 api_key=XXXXXXXX nonce=12345 Signature=XXXXXXXXXXX"\
 -d 'false' https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api/form/:form_id/elements
```

and this is the approach im currently taking:

```
class SeamlessGov
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api"

  def initialize(args={})
    @api_key = args[:api_key]
    @nonce = args[:nonce]
    @signature = generate_signature
  end

  def form(form_id)
    @form = form_id 
  end

  def headers(headers={})
    @headers = headers
  end

  def generate_signature
    # bash command
  end

end
```

Is the best practice to append it or put it in the `base_uri` for example:
`base_uri "https://nycopp.seamlessdocs.com/api/form/:form_id/elements"` or created a method to append to the `base_uri` for example:

```
def append_form(form)
  "/form/#{form}/elements"
end
```

What would the best approach be? So that when I call
`@form = SeamlessGov.new(params, headers)` works.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you would write a method like:

```
def create_form
  get("/form/#{form_id}/elements", headers)
end
```

Which you can then call like:

```
@form = SeamlessGov.new(params, headers).create_form
```